# Login to mac using applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I wrote a little script to open Safari on a remote machine:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set URL of first document to "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
end tell
```

I'd run the applescript remotely because I can connect via SSH.

However, if the machine is not physically logged in (ie, I haven't gone up to it and entered my details), nothing happens. Note, I can still connect to the machine using SSH so can still run scripts.

So can I log the machine in remotely using applescript?

Comment: There might be alternatives to what you're trying to achieve. If you're not logged in, it means you're not in front of the machine so I assume you don't need Safari's graphical interface or interacting with the browser. Could your needs perhaps be served by something non-graphical or non-interactive such as curl or wget?

Comment: @Roadmaster It's for novelty purposes ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
name="theshortname";
password="thePassword";

osascript <<EOF
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab
    keystroke (ASCII character 8)
    keystroke tab
    keystroke (ASCII character 8)
    keystroke return
    delay 0.5
    keystroke tab
    keystroke "$name"
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.5
    keystroke "$password"
    delay 0.5
    keystroke return
    keystroke return
    keystroke return
    keystroke return
end tell
EOF
```

Yes. This is what I use. Just change the first two lines. I do it as root; haven't tested it with sudo. The pauses ensure the text has appeared and the insertion cursor has moved to the next field before continuing. The extra stuff at the beginning ensures the credentials end up in the right fields (ASCII char 8 is backspace).

Known bug: sometimes Snow Leopard's login window will not allow text input despite the blinking insertion cursor. I've not found a way to send the click needed to get actual focus in the name field (a single click with a mouse (even via vnc) makes the script work fine sigh).

Edit: ACK! Forgot to mention that using System Events for GUI interaction depends on the Universal Access system built into OS X. It's just a check-box and only needs to be turned on once. System Preferences > Universal Access > Enable access for assistive devices.

Comment: For clicking, you could use [cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/).  Also, is there a reason you have this as a shell script instead of an AppleScript?

Comment: @antal-s-z Sorry, I should have explained that better; the bulk of it is actually applescript. Inside the '<<EOF' [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) is a block of applescript being handed off to the Open Script Architecture command line program, [osascript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html). osascript is just an easy way to run AS code on the fly via ssh, added to better fit my answer to the asker's situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup autologin via `defaults` command in mac depending on your security requirements. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264068/can-autologin-be-set-up-from-the-command-line-how