# AppleScript: login to logout user

Tags: macos, authentication, applescript, logout

I search for a script way login user that was logout. I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356522/login-to-mac-using-applescript), but it doesn't work for me. I get this error:

```
execution error: An error of type -610 has occurred. (-610)
```

Also I gave all needed permissions to my script, but it didn't help also. Also I checked that another script work for me if user is login (for example, logout or open Safari browser)

So, I concluded there isn't way to run script if user was logout? Maybe I'm wrong and somebody knows how can I solve it?

Comment: You can run scripts on the system level — i.e. when a user is logged out of the system — but the scripts cannot invoke anything with a GUI. You cannot open a Safari window, for instance, unless a user is logged in. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to login to users for few seconds (in programmatically way) for some applications synchronise with internet.

Comment: Specifically, you mean that you need a background system task to log into a user account to synchronize something over the internet? Why does this require a GUI, if in fact there is no user present to interact with the GUI? Apologies, but you need to be ***detailed*** about what you are trying to do, or no one can possible help you.

Comment: Let's say I have user in Mac server for each customer. In each user run applications that they are active only when user is login (for example, FaceTime is synchronised with internet only if user is logged in).  So, I want to run my script periodically through all users and synchronise their applications with internet.

Comment: I don't know precisely what 'synchronizing' you have in mind, but it seems to me that you want a LaunchAgent, not a LaunchDaemon. That way, whenever a user logs in the LaunchAgent will run in that users domain and do whatever synchronizing is needed.

Comment: Synchronizing means all messages were arrived to user telephone will be arrive to mac also. If user is logged out in mac it won't happen.